# Почему не могу загрузить файл через WebDriver? | PHP

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, fileupload

Я пытаюсь загрузить файл примрено так, как это описано в примере: [**tests/functional/FileUploadTest.php**](https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver/blob/main/tests/functional/FileUploadTest.php)

**Мой код** (отрывок):

```php
case 'file-input':
    echo sprintf("\nPath: %s", $field['data']);
    echo sprintf("\nFile exists: %s\n", file_exists($field['data']));

    if (!isset($field['data']))
        return false;

    if (!$this->timeStop($field['xpath']))
        return false;

    $file_input = $this->driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath($field['xpath']));
    $file_input->setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
    $file_input->sendKeys($field['data']);

    if (isset($field['sleep']))
        sleep($field['sleep']);

    break;
```

**Вывод:**

```bash
2023-09-14T09:10:02.806739804Z Path: /var/www/html/yii-application/src/backend/controllers/../../../../cache/ip_0142eb_svidetelstvo.jpg
2023-09-14T09:10:02.806739805Z File exists: 1
```

**Суть проблемы:**

Каждый сайт, на который я пытаюсь загрузить в `input` свой файл - выдает ошибку загрузки. Неважно какой сайт, просто выдает. Причем, сам файл не битый, спокойно открывается. И зачастую в форме даже указано имя файла, но вот сама загрузка не идет на сервер (куда загружаю файл).

Вкладка `Network` (DevTools) не дает особых данных в этом вопросе

**Примечание**:

Сам WebDriver и PHP вообще ни о каких ошибках не говорит. Ошибки на принимающей стороне, или может быть в чем-то другом. Утверждать не могу

Comment: Используется Octo Browser для работы Selenium. Ползунок в профиле (Local Storage) стоит на ON

Answer (score 0):

- Всем спасибо за помощь! Все оказалось очень просто, нашел альтернативу.
  Просто отправляю при помощи `JS` - файл. Делаю `AJAX` запрос на определенном сайте, чтобы отправить данные.

##### Как генерируется файл через JS и с будущей его отправкой (Вдруг, кому надо):

```php
$js = <<<JS
    // Создаем функцию для генерации файла из base64-строки
    function dataURLtoBlob(dataurl, mimeType) {
        var arr = dataurl.split(','),
            bstr = atob(arr[arr.length - 1]), 
            n = bstr.length, 
            u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
                        
        while (n--){
            u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
        }
                        
        return new Blob([u8arr], { type : mimeType });
    }
                    
    // Генерируем Blob из base64 и добавляем его в FormData
    const base64Data = 'data:$mime_type;base64,$base64';  // Замените на вашу base64-строку
    const fileName = 'image.$ext';  // Замените на имя файла
                    
    const blob = dataURLtoBlob(base64Data, '$mime_type');
                    
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', blob, fileName);
                    
    $.ajax({
        url: '<YOUR_URL>',
        method: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
JS;
$this->driver->executeScript($js);
```

- Возможно JS код не идеален, но он решил мой главный вопрос. Даже не приходится загружать файл в `<input>`